# How to run a docker container for integration testing a Spring Boot app within VSTS

Tags: docker, spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The problem is how to run a Docker database image within VSTS and then run a Maven task to package a Spring Boot application.

The goal is to be able to perform integration testing with a real database that can be destroyed after the build has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL is being used within the database container, could be any DB.  Create a Docker Run task.  Make sure to select **Run in Background**

[image]

Next step is important, VSTS will not allow you to connect to the running database container via localhost or 127.0.0.1.  Use a shell script to find out the IP of the running database container.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IP=`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' database`
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL;]jdbc:postgresql://$IP:5432/myDatabase"
```

This script will find out the IP of the container and create the datasource URL based on the IP.

[image]

Run Maven package as usual, now you can test against a database, run liquibase/flyway etc... without being concerned about maintaining an external database for integration testing.

[image]

Make sure to remove the Docker container as part of the build cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Our build agent is a *nix based machine. We create services and Postgres DB as docker images and use tmpfs for the integration testing.

Please refer the below blog more details

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-run-integration-tests-at-warp-speed-with-docker-and-tmpfs/